# Creating a virtual Python 3.3.2 environment using virtualenv

Tags: macos, python-3.x, virtualenv, pip, python-3.3

Recently I installed Python 3.3 using the Mac OSX installer. Following which I installed pip-3.3 following the instructions of [How to use pip with Python 3.x besides Python 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-besides-python-2-x), the second answer. After which I ran the following command to install `virtualenv`,

```
sudo pip-3.3 install virtualenv
```

Updated my `PATH` variable as well as follows:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/python:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

`PYTHONPATH` variable is as follows:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
```

However, when I run `virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 py3`, I get the following [Error message](http://pastebin.com/EdTfnAVZ).

I observed that, on many posts and questions answered on StackOverflow as well, the usage is always `-p /usr/bin/python3` however in my case there is no directory like `python3` in `/usr/bin/`. There's one in `/usr/local/bin/`. Is this strange and incorrect?

Kindly help me out here. How should I go about it? And what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Chintak

Comment: You should not need to modify any environment variables just to get virtualenv working. My guess is that your change means two different versions of virtualenv or pip get's mixed up. Undo the environment changes and try again.

Comment: @LennartRegebro so use ``/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:`` as `PYTHONPATH` ? I even have Python 2.7 installed. If I set the above as `PYTHONPATH` it tries to search in `site-packages` of 2.7.

Comment: I think the error lies in `virtualenv` trying to install `pip`. My `pip` command points to `pip` for Python 2.7. `pip-3.3` points to pip for Python 3.3. Could this be the problem?

Comment: In a normal install, you do not have PYTHONPATH set at all. No, it's not a problem, just use pip-3.3 when you want to install for Python 3.3.

Comment: http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/newbie-hint-on-installing-python-and-its-modules-and-packages/