# Import Request not found

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I just started a new project and the client gave me a new Mac Book Pro along with some Python scripts that they developed. Unfortunately, I cant' seem to get the Python script to run correctly.

I am new to using a Mac.

When I try to run the Python program, I get an error at "import requests" line despite that I have installed the requests module via pip. It may be an issue with I am new to Python and Mac and downloaded the latest Python before I realized that 2.7 is pre-installed or it could be something completely different.

The first 2 lines in the file `xxx.py` seem to work

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
```

Error:

```
File /Users/ad/Downloads/xxx.py, Line 5, in <module>
     from import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

From Terminal:

```
ADs-MacBook-Pro:Downloads ad$ pip3 list

pip (1.5.6)

requests (2.4.1)

setuptools (2.1) 

ADs-MacBook-Pro:Downloads ad$ echo "$PATH"

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated...

By the way, from the downloads folder that I am running the `xxx.py` file from I get:

```
$ python

Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
...
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
```

But from the folder that has requests library

```
ad$ pwd
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.4.1
```

I get it to work in TERMINAL

```
requests-2.4.1 ad$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
...
>>> import requests
```

So I suspect its a PATH or environment variable setup error.

Comment: How are you running the script? Are you sure it's running with Python 3?

Comment: did you use sudo to install? that is.. *`sudo` pip install requests*?

Comment: Are you sure this is the error message? It seems to be wrong. Try to run on console `python3 -c "import requests"`, check the result and update the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `pip3`, you're using the pip associated with python 3.x. You need to execute your script with the related python 3. Try this:

```
python3 yourscript.py
```

Comment: ...or conversely, install requests again with pip for python 2.x. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x).

Answer (score 0):

There is a few issues on this problem.

Are you using virtualenv? If yes, maybe you are forgettting to activate it.

You said that you installed packages using pip3, but trying to run script using Python2.7. Install packages using correct pip version or run script with Python 3. As @josh-smeaton already pointed.

You should add this line below in the first line of your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Or this for Python 3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```