# pip installation on different python version

Tags: python, django, pip

I encounter a problem with `pip` installation on linux. I've python 2.7 and 3.4, also Django in 1.7 installed. Currently I'm working on a project which uses different versions and I'm unable to install packages trough `pip` on python 2.7. Everything goes to directory of 3.4. 
Is there any way to "force" `pip` to install packages in concrete version of python?

Comment: you should use virtual enviornment if you have multiple version of python.

Comment: Your system seems to be using python3 as the default python version. What os are you using? Are you on Gentoo or Arch?

Comment: no it's mint and as default python 2.7 is used. If I want to use python 3.4 I need to force the system by `python3` command. But `pip install` uses python 3.4.

Comment: check for packages in your distro for pip. There should be one for python2 and one for python3. Install the one for python2. You should then be able to run `pip-2.7` or `pip-python2` to install packages for python2.

Comment: If you can't find it in your distro, install it by hand. Have a look at this question, particularly this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x#comment14822876_11272201

Answer (score 0):

The usual, and recommended by most users, way of working with Django is to use a separate, virtual environment per project.

Use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to set up your Python 2.x environment and [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for Python 3.x. Both will install their own, local version of pip. [Google lists lots of tutorials](https://www.google.de/search?q=Python%20Django&gws_rd=ssl#q=Django%20Virtualenv) if you need help beyond the documentation.

Comment: I didn't thought about `virtualenv` :). Thanks I'll try this.