# How to specify using Python 3's Version of PIP (or why isn't PIP working)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I have a mac that has both `Python 2.7.6` installed (by default) and `Python 3.4.0` installed (by me).

I think that I may also have multiple versions of PIP installed. (When I run `PIP --version` I get `pip 1.5.6 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)`

But I know that `Python 3` comes with version `1.5.4`.

So, my questions are:

**A.** How do I find out if I have multiple versions of `pip` installed.

**B.** If I do have multiple versions installed, how do I specify which one to use, or where the installed packages should go?

I have tried the suggestion outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x) (basically using `pip-3.4`) but I get `command not found`

The reason for all of this is that when trying to install any package with `pip`, even just to update (`pip install --upgrade pip`) I get the following errors

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1431, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 598, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1836, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 295, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/dependency_links.txt'

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Startec/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Comment: Have you tried ``pip3``? Also, in general, you can write the start of a command in the Terminal and press tab twice -- this will show a list of possible expansions. (If there's only one it will be completed after just the first press.)

Comment: have you tried pip3 or pip3.4?

Answer (score 1):

Just like `python` is symlinked to your Python 2 version, `pip` is symlinked to Python 2’s pip.

Instead, use `pip3` which should refer to the active Python 3 installation (accessible using `python3`). You can also use the full version name, but then without a dash: `pip3.4`.

Comment: This was it. As @mmdeas mentioned, pressing tab showed me the other versions of pip I had installed which in this case was `pip     pip2    pip2.7  pip3    pip3.4  `