# Why doesn't pip (or pipX) work for Python3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.4

According to [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-pep-453), Python3.4, which I am using, ships with `pipX` or `pipX.Y`. When I type `pip3` or `pip3.4` into my terminal, I get a `"command not found"`.

I am also using Python2.7 and have `pip` installed for that. When I type `pip --version` I get:

```
pip 6.0.7 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Why doesn't `pip3` or `pip3.4` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying both answers provided, I kept running into odd Python issues. For example, I received a `zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available` error when running `sudo python3 get-pip.py` and `Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 1.5.6 requires SSL/TLS` error when running `python3.4 -m ensurepip`. It looked like I was missing many of the dependencies that come with a typical Python bui

I uninstalled Python 3.4 using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4/3819829#3819829), reinstalled Python 3.4, and now the `pip3` command works.

Answer (score 2):

[How to use pip with Python 3.x alongside Python 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x)

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
```

1567K download

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py  

Collecting pip
   Downloading pip-6.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |################################| 1.3MB 336kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip

Successfully installed pip-6.0.7
```

> me@fissionchips:~$ `pip3 -V`
>
> pip 6.0.7 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (python 3.4)

Comment: I tried this and received a zipimport error. I'm not sure why, but it looks like my build of Python was atypical. I just reinstalled Python 3.4, and now `pip3` works.