# python3.4 pip ImportError: No Module named 'pkg_resources'

Tags: python, pip

pip is not working in my python3.4

```
$ pip install django
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
      from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
      from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

How do I fix this? What's the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i just ran into the same error, here is what i've done to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python-pkg-resources

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try >sudo pip install django< I think that ought to do it
well then I suspect your pip is messed up so try
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pkg-resources
however if you are using Python 3 you may need to adjust to insure that you get the Python 3 environment set up rather than the P2 default
see here for more on that 
[How to use pip with Python 3.x alongside Python 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x)

Comment: Nope, still the same ImportError. I'm very new to linux sorry.