# How to install beautifulsoup into python3, when default dir is python2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip

I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 installed. When I type `pip install beautifulsoup4` it tells me that it is already installed in python2.7/site-package directory.

But how do I install it into the python3 dir?

Comment: By running `pip3` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use pip with Python 3.x alongside Python 2.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I think pip3 will satisfy your needs, use the below command on the terminal:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

See [doc](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Answer (score 15):

Run as root:

```
apt-get install python3-bs4
#or
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Afterwards import it like this:

```
import bs4
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why it is installed as beautifulsoup4 and called as bs4?

Comment: @Mischief_Monkey No, I don't know but probably so you don't have to write `import beautifulsoup4 as bs4` it saves a lot of typing when you try to access classes from the module e.g. `bs4.PageElement`

Answer (score 7):

If you’re using a recent version of Debian or Ubuntu Linux, you can install Beautiful Soup with the system package manager:

```
$ apt-get install python-bs4 (for Python 2)
$ apt-get install python3-bs4 (for Python 3)
```

Afer install import the library

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 3):

The package is bs4 and can be installed with following command:

```
python -m pip install bs4
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some mismatch between Python version and Beautifulsoup. I was installing this project
*Th3Jock3R/LinuxGSM-Arma3-Mod-Update*
to a linux centos8 dedicated Arma3 server. Python3 and Beautifulsoup4 seem to match.So I updated Python3, removed manually Beautifulsoup files and re-installed it with: **sudo yum install python3-beautifulsoup4** (note the number 3). Works. Then pointing directories in Th3Jock3R:s script A3_SERVER_FOLDER = "" and A3_SERVER_DIR = "/home/arma3server{}".format(A3_SERVER_FOLDER) placing and running the script in same folder /home/arma3server with **python3 update.py**. In this folder is also located new folder called 'modlists' Now the lightness of mod loading blows my mind. -Bob-

Comment: Pinpointed the location of files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, this works for Python3 as well
`py -m pip install bs4`