# No module named 'beautifulsoup4' in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
$ virtualenv test
$ source test/bin/activate
$ pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Now the script test.py

```
import urllib.request
import sys
import unittest, time, re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Sel(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.base_url = "file:///Users/ishandutta2007/Desktop/cars/cars-price-list.html"

    def test_sel(self):
        with urllib.request.urlopen(self.base_url) as url:
            html_source = url.read()
        data = html_source#.encode('utf-8')
        parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

when I run `$python3 test.py`

> File "test.py", line 6, in 
>       from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

then tried with

```
from beautifulsoup4 import BeautifulSoup
```

> File "test.py", line 6, in 
>       from beautifulsoup4 import BeautifulSoup ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'

requirements clearly shows both

```
$ pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
$ cat requirements.txt 
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.6
requests==2.18.4
urllib3==1.22
```

Comment: maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507744/how-to-install-beautifulsoup-into-python3-when-default-dir-is-python2-7

check pip freeze if it's really installed.

Comment: replace `beautifulsoup4` with `bs4`

Comment: @codekaizer check update

Answer (score 17):

Only install `BeautifulSoup4` instead of `bs4` and `BeautifulSoup` then,

**do this:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: in starting of your question you `pip3 install beautifulsoup4` then you also do `pip3 install bs4` i am saying that only do `pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: assume I have not done ```pip3 install bs4```, now answer.

Comment: then change the file name it maybe possible that python is executing some other test.py

Answer (score 1):

I would do this for a work around:

All of this under your created virtual environment

```
$ wget https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4
$ pip3 install beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
$ pip3 freeze |grep beautifulsoup4
$ python3
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not in the right place; cd test and try again.

Here's the problem: Python uses the PYTHONPATH environment variable to look for packages, and by default that includes your current directory. However, the BeautifulSoup4 package is installed under the test directory. If you start Python *from* the test directory, it should be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, virtualenv was installed with python2.7,

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to delete `thebeautifulsoup4-4.8.0.dist-info` and `bs4` folders from `C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` and again performed `pip install beautifulsoup4` on command prompt.
It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

`import bs4` worked for me. Both using an Anaconda env or Pip

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.