# Installing modules to wrong python version

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm currently running both Python 3.5 and 2.7 on my Mac. While installing modules and working on 3.5, I'm running into errors as some installations fail (installation is attempted for 2.7 and access is denied).

How do i specify the path to the python 3 folder? python 3.5 is saved in a weird location nowhere near where 2.7 is.

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5

This is different from where python 2.7 is saved, for which the installation is going through normally when 3.5 isn't running.

> /Library/Python/2.7

For instance, here is the error displayed to me on terminal while installing virtualenv.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/294Oa.png)

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer to this question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x)

Comment: Or see if you have `pip3` installed.

Comment: as far as I'm given to understand, pip comes installed with python 3.4+

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is **highly** recommended to use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to create isolated Python environments and install libraries only into these. Do this and avoid installing any libraries into the main Python version, except for `virtualenv` itself of course :) When you do so, one you've activated a specific `virtualenv`, `pip` will just work.

If you still decide you want to install a library outside of a `virtualenv`, the safest way to make sure you're using the `pip` for the right version of Python is this:

```
python35 -m pip install ...
```

(replace `python35` with however you invoke the relevant version of Python)

Comment: so is that how i should install virtualenv to start with?
as in (>> python35 -m pip install virtualenv)

and then install the others in the virtualenv

Comment: Indeed, that would work. It doesn't really matter which version of Python you use virtualenv with, though; you can tell virtualenv which Python interpreter to use whenever you set up a new env.