# Using pip version with Python 3.x alongside Python 2.x on Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pip

My question is thoroughly based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x). The big difference is I'm focusing on windows here. The answers/question provided there were for unix distributions.

I've ran Python 2.x for quite a while and have used pip with no problems.

Now I've installed python 3 but when I open the cmd prompt and `pip install somemodule` it tries to install it for python 2. How can I deal with this situation ?

Both Python's were installed with the Anaconda distribution so I believe both of them come with pip installed. Note: This info come from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)

EDIT:
Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions) which addresses that issue.

But now when I try to run the command

```
pip3.5 install pymssql
```

or

```
pip-3.5 install pymssql
```

I get the error `pip3.5 is an unknown command`.

If I open cmd and type `python` I receive:

```
Python 3.5.1 Anaconda 4.0.0
```

so it shouldn't be a version problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to make sure you have the correct Anaconda environment activated, which it looks like you have in this case.

```
conda env list   # Display the list of conda environments
```

[image]

In the Windows Command Prompt you should just need to use:

```
activate py35   # Or whatever your Python 3.5 environment is called. (Mine is root)
pip install pymssql
```

Instead of `pip-3.5`.

To install it in another environment (mine is called py27):

```
activate py27
pip install pymssql
```

I successfully used this command in both my Python 2.7 and 3.5 Anaconda environments.

To go back to your primary environment (root), just type `activate` without an environment name after it

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ! it didn't work for me though. When I use ``conda env list`` all I get is a ``root`` pointing to Anaconda3. really weird

Comment: I installed it for my user only, do you think that might be an issue ?

Comment: I installed for all users. doesn't change

Comment: just realized, the problem is only for installing pyodbc... thanks a lot for the help though

Comment: Do you have your Python 2.7 environment installed apart from Anaconda?

Comment: I don't ! should I ? how ?

Comment: Looks like if you are only having an issue with pyodbc, you should be able to use `conda install pyodbc`

Comment: Great! Happy to hear that!