# redis in python3.5.1 interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, redis

I installed redis with pip, and in Python2 interpreter, it's ok to 
    import redis

But, in Python3 interpreter, I got 
**ImportError: No module named 'redis'**

So why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

When you install redis by 'sudo pip install redis', actually you install redis driver to path which python2.x uses (take OS X for example) :

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis
```

If install with python3, it will be installed to path :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis-2.10.5-py3.5.egg
```

It's different if you use other os, but that's why you can import redis using python3.

If you want to use redis with python3, there are two ways to do this:

1) build redis from source:

```
https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py.git  
cd redis-py  
python3 setup.py install
```

2) install pip for python3, you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x).

Comment: Great, it works! And I understand the reason, thanks very much!