# Getting ImportError while importing keras

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras, ubuntu-16.04

I have followed every step for installing keras but whenever I am trying to import keras it gives me an error No module named tensorflow. But I have already installed tensorflow.
[image]

I have two questions-
1. How can I solve this particular ImportError?
2. If possible can anyone give me a detailed step by step instruction on installing theano, tensorflow and keras? Please don't give any links to install keras because i have tried them all but they keep giving some kind of error or problem.

If possible please take a look at my other question since they are related [No module named keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369275/no-module-named-keras/41371747#41371747)

Thank You

Comment: Maybe installed for two different versions of Python?

Comment: So what should i do next if i want to keep the 3.5 version?

Comment: I'm guessing there won't be an issue if you want to install them side-by-side.

Comment: if i wanted to start afresh what should i do then?

Comment: I might try installing both, and then if not, Google away to find out how to completely uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Try sudo -H python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow