# How do I get pyodbc to install for Python 3.5?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyodbc

I installed pyodbc on my Raspberry Pi with the following

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyodbc
```

and

```
pip install pyodbc
```

When I try to import pyodbc, I can only do so in the Python 2.7 Shell. In Python 3.5 Shell I get "No Module named 'pyodbc'. How can I ensure the pyodbc is enabled for Python 3.5 when I install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use pip with Python 3.x alongside Python 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you install pip, there are a few versions of pip that you can call. On my machine (not RP though):

```
myid@mymachine:~$ pip
pip     pip2    pip2.7  pip3    pip3.5  pip3.6  pipenv
```

You can use pip3 to install packages for your python3.