# How to make sure pip installs packages to python 3?

Tags: python

I am seeing some weird stuff on my system:

```
$ pip install python-binance-api
...Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from python-binance-api) (3.13.2)
...
```

python versions:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.14
 10:05 PM   ~/kittycapital   add_more_curr
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.4
```

My pip is still installing to python 2.7 when I want it to install on python3. How do I get it to do this?

If I want the commands `pip` and `python` to point to python 3.7, what can I do?

Comment: It's 2018, and there's still no one accepted answer to this question. Seems to change every year. Here are some ways: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x

Comment: Why did you bring `scala` into the mix here?

Comment: If I want the commands `pip` and `python` to point to python 3.7, what can I do?

Comment: Use `pip3` instead of `pip`

Comment: Is there anyway to change `pip` to mean `pip3` on my system without using something like bash aliases?

Comment: Yes, symlink it.

Comment: IMHO the best way to solve this problem is to use virtualenvs people!

Comment: `sudo mv /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip` if you're the rebellious type

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

```
python3 -m pip install xxx
# for example: python3.7 -m pip install requests
```

Solution 2

```
virtualenv --python=python3.7 venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install requests
```

Solution 3

```
pipenv --python 3.7   # python3 -m pip install pipenv --user
pipenv shell
pipenv install requests
```