# Python2.7 no smb module. Cant locate

Tags: python, python-3.x, smb

Running kali 2020, I am trying to run CVE-2007-2447 which is a python2.7 script, which says:

```
import smb

from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
```

I saved the script to a file and ran it, but I get `ImportError: No module named smb`. In the script, it says install *pysmb* by running `pip install --user pysmb`.
I did this, but still the same error message.

I tried to locate pysmb and found these packages:

```
$ locate pysmb            
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pysmbc-1.0.23.egg-info
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pysmbc-1.0.23.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pysmbc-1.0.23.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pysmbc-1.0.23.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/share/system-config-printer/pysmb.py
/usr/share/system-config-printer/__pycache__/pysmb.cpython-39.pyc
```

I have had a problem before where packages only install for python3 and I have to copy the folders to python2.7. I tried that for this without success.

When I googled module smb, it comes up with samba. I installed the samba package but still nothing. Does anyone know how I can get smb module to python2.7?

Comment: Just as a note, it's better to install modules for Python 2 using pip rather than copying the module folders.

Comment: @DapperDuck Cheers mate. How do i install to python2? Everything automatically installs to python3...

Comment: Wasn't pip just recently disabled for Python 2?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install using the Python 2.7 pip. Use the following command:

```
pip2.7 install pysmb
```

Answer (score 1):

Pip no longer supports Python 2.

[pip documentation v21.0.1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use python 2 pip to install the module, instead of installing it for python 3. See [How to use pip with Python 3.x alongside Python 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x)
.

Comment: I tried to install pip2.7 as the link says and i get 

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I tried to paste the output but it put it all on one line when i hit enter...?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was simple.
I named the python script file 'smb.py'. 'smb.py' and'pysmb' were in conflict.